# validate date in python

Tags: python, django

I need to validate a date that comes from the front and say that I am over 13 years and I have the code the only thing missing is what goes into the if thanks for your help

```
   import datetime


  class LegalAgeValidator:
  LEGAL_BASE_AGE = 13

  def __init__(self):
  self.base_age = LEGAL_BASE_AGE

 def __call__(self, value): 
 if  
    message = 'age not allowed to register.' % self.base_age
    raise serializers.ValidationError(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the `value` is the *date of birth*, you can calculate the number of full years by first subtracting `value`s year from the current year and then subtract an extra one if today is before this year's birthday. Then we can check if the number of *full* years (`dy`) is less tah `self.base_age`. If that is the case, we raise an error:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class LegalAgeValidator:
    LEGAL_BASE_AGE = 13

    def __init__(self, base_age=LEGAL_BASE_AGE):
        self.base_age = base_age

    def __call__(self, value):
        td = now().date()
        dy = td.year - value.year
        dy -= (td.month, td.day) < (value.month, value.day)
        if dy < self.base_age:
            message = 'age not allowed to register.' % self.base_age
            raise serializers.ValidationError(message)
```

This thus means that the validator will accept birthdays if these are more or exactly thirteen years ago. This thus means that if we validate the value on September 12<sup>th</sup>, 2020, that a person born on October 14<sup>th</sup>, 2007; is not yet of legal age, and a person born on September 1<sup>st</sup>, 2007; is of legal age according to the validator.